# Multiple series using highcharts-chart

Tags: highcharts, polymer

I started using the highcharts-chart library for polymer but I cannot figure out how to add multiple series of data to a single graph. 
The addSeries function can't be recognized somehow so what other options do I have?

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I have a JSON Response like:
{
  "costPerUnit": [
    {
      "bIMOrSemiOrAutoMainanence": 12.34,
      "scheduledService": 23,
      "wearAndTear": 1.782,
      "total": 3109578.8
    },
    {
      "bIMOrSemiOrAutoMainanence": 19.34,
      "scheduledService": 0,
      "wearAndTear": 1.782,
      "total": 3938431.8
    },
    {
      "bIMOrSemiOrAutoMainanence": 20.34,
      "scheduledService": 18,
      "wearAndTear": 2.254,
      "total": 5277066.5
    }
  ]
}
I want to plot a line graph in the same chart for all the attributes. How do i achieve that?

Comment: Do you use some specific plugin/wrapper for Highcharts, or just the official library? Also, include in your question (edit your question) code you are using for generating chart. We don't know how your structure looks like etc.